# GraphQL Query with variables from data object

Tags: graphql, gatsby, prismic.io

I have a graphQl query where I use a Prismic uid to get a specific user. Now I also want to get a user space from another prismic set of data called prismicSpaces but instead of looking for the data based on the uid on prismicSpaces I want to pass it an identifier from prismicUsers data object called location_id. Seen as location_id is not at the root like uid how can I use that to pass it down to prismicSpaces ?

below is my current query which works great but I need a way to pass on the location_id like the second example below this.

ps. I'm using gatsby and prismic

```
export const query = graphql`
  query UsersQuery($uid: String!) {
    page: prismicUsers(uid: { eq: $uid }) {
      uid
      type
      data {
        location_id
        }
      }
    }
    spaces: prismicSpaces {
      uid
      data {
       name
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

Example but this does not work.

```
export const query = graphql`
  query UsersQuery($uid: String!, $space_id:String! ) {
    page: prismicUsers(uid: { eq: $uid }) {
      uid
      type
      data {
        space_id
        }
      }
    }
    spaces: prismicSpaces(uid: {eq: { $space_id }) {
      uid
      data {
       name
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

Comment: Anyone know how to do this ?